# Rails -PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: malformed array literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

```
add_column :ssr_service_markets, :origin, :string, array: true, default: []
```

and when i want to

```
SSRService::Market.where(origin: "*", destination: "*").first
```

I have got

`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "*"
LINE 1: ...service_markets"  WHERE "ssr_service_markets"."origin" = '*' 
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

*In Postgres, to check if an array **contains** given element, you can use `@>` array operator.*

Read more: [Array Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html)

---

`:origin` is an array field in your `ssr_service_markets` table, which means that it can contain multiple values.

In your example, assuming that `destination` is an array field as well, you could try to do the searching this way:

```
Model.where(["origin @> ? AND destination @> ?", '{*}', '{*}')"])
```

Remember about using **curly braces** when working with [array values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT).

> To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element
>   values within curly braces [...]

Comment: You're usually better off using the `array[...]` syntax (`where('origin @> array[?]', '*')`), fewer quoting issues that way and AR will even expand an array into the placeholder properly without any extra chicanery. With one element you could also say [`? = any(origin)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21103).